# Can a functorial factorization be modified so that it fixes the initial object?

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories

Consider a category $\mathcal C$ with a weak factorization system which is functorial. Let $*$ be an initial object. If $X\in \mathcal C$, denote by $\eta_X:*\to X$ the unique map. Using the given wfs, it factors as as $*\stackrel{\eta_{QX}}{\to} QX \stackrel{q_X}{\to} X $.

Consider the following assertion:

> (A) The maps $Q\eta_X:Q*\to QX$ and $Q*\stackrel{q_*}{\to} * \stackrel{\eta_{QX}}{\to} QX$ coincide.

This is a minimalistic scenario: I'm interested in the situation where $\mathcal C$ is a (cofibrantly generated) model category with functorial factorizations and the wfs is (cofibrations, acyclic fibrations), so $Q$ is a cofibrant replacement functor. I would like to know the following:

> Is it possible to modify the functorial factorization of the wfs (cofibrations, acyclic fibrations) of $\mathcal C$ without changing the model category structure (i.e. keeping the same classes of cofibrations, fibrations, weak equivalences) so that assertion (A) is true?

Manipulating some diagrams and the condition of functoriality lets us conclude that (A) is true if $q_X:QX\to X$ is a monomorphism, or if $\eta_{Q*}:*\to Q*$ is an epimorphism.

> Is it possible to modify the functorial factorization of the wfs (cofibrations, acyclic fibrations) so that $\eta_{Q*}$ is an epimorphism? An isomorphism? The identity $id_*$?

We could be more ambitious with this last question: it would be nice if we could change the functorial factorization so that it factors any identity map through identity maps (rather than asking that it does this just with the identity map of $*$).

For background, I'd add that my category $\mathcal C$ is the category of commutative $\mathbb S$-algebras of Elmendorf, Kriz, Mandell, May (EKMM), so $*$ is $\mathbb S$.

Comment: @HarryGindi That's indeed the case! I'll edit it in, thank you.

Comment: Ah, in this case is it not possible to just re-define $Q\ast$ to be $\ast$ itself, and leave the rest of the values of $Q$ unchanged? I think all of the relevant naturality squares will automatically commute, since $\ast$ is initial.

Comment: @AaronMazel-Gee That's what I said in chat last week, but I wasn't sure enough to give it as an answer.  It's like a cheeky extension by zero of the restriction to $C-\{*\}$

Comment: @AaronMazel-Gee I don't see how this would work. For simplicity, suppose instead of modifying the whole functorial factorization we just modify the functor $Q$, so we ask ourselves whether we can construct $Q'$, an endofunctor of $\mathcal C$ such that $Q’X$ is $QX$ if $X\not= *$ and is $*$ if $X=*$. OK, then on an arrow $X\to Y$ it should be $QX\to QY$ if $X,Y\not= *$, it should be $*\to QY$ if $X=*$, and it should be $QX\to Q*\to *$ if $X\not=*$ and $Y=*$. But this is not always a functor.

Comment: @HarryGindi (cont.) Indeed, consider a composition $X\stackrel{f}{\to} *\stackrel{g}{\to} Z$ where $X$ and $Z$ are not $*$. Then $Q’$ maps the composition to $QX\to Q*\to QZ$. On the other hand, the composition of the $Q’$’s of these arrows is $QX\to Q*\to *\to QZ$. So now the question is whether $Qg:Q*\to QZ$ is equal to $Q*\to *\to QZ$, which is a case of assertion (A) above, which doesn’t hold for $Q$ (if it did, there would be no need to go through all this).

Comment: @BrunoStonek That's why I didn't give you an answer =).  I still think that the functor can be rectified, but not sure.  I think something could possibly work if you have a zero object, but not sure about the case of 'rings'.

Comment: @BrunoStonek thanks for spelling that out -- of course, this becomes simpler when the initial object is empty.  I think this is equivalent to the canonical functor $(C \backslash \{ \emptyset \})^\triangleleft \to C$ being an equivalence, which is where Harry's "extension by zero" would apply.

Comment: @AaronMazel-Gee If $*$ is a zero object (is this what you meant by “empty”?), then a similar naïve definition of a $Q’$ as above also won’t work. Again, consider $X\to *\to Y$; on one hand it should go to $QX\to Q*\to QY$, and on the other hand it should go to $QX\to *\to QY$. This leads to exactly the same problem as before.

What does the little triangle mean in your displayed arrow?

Comment: I think he’s using empty to mean there’s no maps *to* the initial object other than the identity- so that your counterexample doesn’t apply. The lil arrow is ‘left cone’ ie that category with one new object that maps to everything else uniquely and has no maps back.